# ESP8266 compilation error: "previous declaration of 'HTTPMethod HTTP_HEAD'"

Tags: esp8266, library, compilation-errors, progmem

I have an ESP8266 program that used to work but is now failing to compile with this error:

```
C:\...\Arduino\libraries\WiFiManager/WiFiManager.h:25:24: note: in expansion of macro 'PROGMEM'

 const char HTTP_HEAD[] PROGMEM            = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no\"/><title>{v}</title>";

                        ^

In file included from C:\...\MyEsp.ino:14:0:

C:\...AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\ESP8266WebServer\src/ESP8266WebServer.h:33:39: error: previous declaration of 'HTTPMethod HTTP_HEAD'

 enum HTTPMethod { HTTP_ANY, HTTP_GET, HTTP_HEAD, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT, HTTP_PATCH, HTTP_DELETE, HTTP_OPTIONS };
                                   ^
```

I don't recall changing anything, except maybe updating some libraries. Any ideas what could be causing this?  Here are my includes from the ESP8266 program:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

#include <DNSServer.h>            //Local DNS Server used for redirecting all requests to the configuration portal
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>     //Local WebServer used to serve the configuration portal
#include <WiFiManager.h>          //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager WiFi Configuration Magic

#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 256
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a newer version of the WiFiManager.h library. This issue was [fixed August last year.](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/commit/ff26ed4e4c1c34465e182af1cde0eb9e8dda6c4a)

Comment: Strange. WiFiManager.h didn't show up in my 'Updateable' libraries but you're right.